# LibGDX - touchUp event not being handled by another Actor

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I have a mobile game which has a level select menu. The menu consists of 15 level buttons per page and of 4 pages. Page can be changed by swiping the screen. Swiping can be done over the buttons (it can start and end on a button) without triggering any of them. Buttons can be tapped which should activate their touchUp() method.

**Currently the dragging works properly but the level select buttons are not handling the touchUp events.**

I have done this by creating an actor that is the size of the whole screen. It is behaving as the dragHandler actor which detects touchDown, touchDragged and touchUp. It is working properly.

Under the dragHandler actor (on the stage) lies all the level button actors that move on the screen as the user drags it. Because the dragHandler is above the buttons, the buttons touchDown or touchUp methods are not called, the events are being handled in the dragHandler.

In my dragHandlers InputListeners touchUp method I have a piece of code that checks if the drag was long enough to be interpreted as a drag. If it wasn't, the event should be marked as unhandled. However, the InputListeners touchUp method prototype is returning a void so it cannot tell the lower levels that the event wasn't really handled (the touch seems to be marked as handled in the touchDown method already).

**Here is my version of the InputListener in the dragHandler:**

```
dragHandler.addListener(new MyInputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        // Mark dragging on, save drag start position
        dragStartX = x;
        isDragging = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        // If the drag was long enough, mark the event as handled
        if (Math.abs(dragXOffset) >= minDrag) {
            // Do stuff
            return true;
        }
        else
            // Return false to tell that this event was not yet handled,
            // and should be handled by another actor (in this case, a level select button)
            return false;
    }

    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            dragXOffset = x - dragStartX;
            updateLevelButtonPositionsToDraggedX();
    }
}
```

I have made a new class called MyInputListener which is exactly the same class as the original InputListener.java but I have changed the touchUp method to return a boolean instead of void, and changed the switch-case to return its result (instead of a constant true). This however didn't affect in any way. I guess it is because the touchDown event is being already handled in the dragHandler, so the touchUp cannot be handled by a different EventListener anymore.

All the actors are on the same stage, and the applications input processor is set to be the stage. If I put the dragHandler below the button actors, the touchUp method of a button is called always when the touchUp event is fired on top of a button. I don't want the touchUp after a drag to trigger the touchUp event of any of the buttons.

Is there any way to achieve what I want with any approach similar to what I have done already?

Thank you for your time!